# Python how i find a specific string and add behind to an list

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist

how can I save a specific string from a text file into an array/list?

Textfile.txt:

```
...
  Certificate Name: domain1.com
    Domains: domain1.com
    Expiry Date: 2020-08-17 17:56:08+00:00 (VALID: 41 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: domain2.com
    Domains: domain2.com
    Expiry Date: 2020-08-17 17:56:08+00:00 (VALID: 31 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: domain3.com
    Domains: domain3.com
    Expiry Date: 2020-08-17 17:56:08+00:00 (VALID: 13 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain3.com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain3.com/privkey.pem
...
```

Now the question is how to get the "**Certificate Name:**" into a list in Python and only this one.

*With Bash is easy when i use "grep -oP '(?<=Certificate Name:).*'*

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can use `str.split()`:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    s = f.readlines()

lst = [l.split()[-1] for l in s if l.strip().startswith('Certificate Name: ')]

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com']
```

Comment: I would use more explicit variable names than `s` and `l` which make me think spontaneously of a string and a list. Maybe `lines` and `line` instead?

Comment: Wow looks very easy. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

This provides a neater output and should allow you to understand the code better! Good Luck!

```
# Create List
completeList = []

# Make Python Open File in READ MODE...
with open("Textfile.txt", "r") as source_file:
    for line in source_file:
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        # If the current line contains the string below...
        if stripped_line.count("Certificate Name") != 0:
            # Add to List!
            completeList.append(stripped_line)
        else:
            continue

# Print each certificate name separately...
for item in completeList:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
Certificate Name: domain1.com
Certificate Name: domain2.com
Certificate Name: domain3.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather go for regex than loop through line by line.

```
import re
 
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()

print(re.findall("(Certificate Name: .*.com)", txt))
```

Output:

```
['Certificate Name: domain1.com',
 'Certificate Name: domain2.com',
 'Certificate Name: domain3.com']
```